# python regex pattern to get stracer output

Tags: python, regex, python-re

```
write(1, "\33(B\33[0;1m\33[90m3.8\33[4;52H", 24) = 24
```

I would like to get each value in between `()` the string before `()` and the number after the `=`

Sometimes it can be a `-#`

Sample of out

```
close(4)                                = 0

openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9392/statm", O_RDONLY) = 4

read(4, "2387 878 750 226 0 163 0\n", 512) = 25

read(4, "", 487)                        = 0

close(4)                                = 0

openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9392/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4

read(4, "9392 (strace) S 9330 9330 9 3481"..., 2048) = 319

read(4, "", 1729)                       = 0

close(4)                                = 0

openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9407/task", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
```

What I have tried:

for the args

```py
"(.*?)"
```

string at the beginning

```py
(.*?)\(
```

I just need the number.

Are there more efficient ways of what I'm doing?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Have you written any code? Are you getting any error messages? Can you provide some sample inputs and your expected outputs?

Comment: @Avra my input varies but the structure is the same. I added sample above

Comment: @ddejohn just did.

Comment: Can you very explicitly demonstrate your desired output for each of those lines? E.g., `close(4) = 0 -> close 4 0`?

Comment: Sometimes *what* can be a `-#`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not totally sure what exactly you're looking for but this seems to work:

```py
import re


pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)\((.*)\)\s*=\s*(.*)")


lines = ['close(4)                                = 0',
         'openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9392/statm", O_RDONLY) = 4',
         'read(4, "2387 878 750 226 0 163 0\\n", 512) = 25',
         'read(4, "", 487)                        = 0',
         'close(4)                                = 0',
         'openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9392/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4',
         'read(4, "9392 (strace) S 9330 9330 9 3481"..., 2048) = 319',
         'read(4, "", 1729)                       = 0',
         'close(4)                                = 0',
         'openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9407/task", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 4']


for line in lines:
    print(pattern.findall(line)
```

Output:

```py
[('close', '4', '0')]
[('openat', 'AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9392/statm", O_RDONLY', '4')]
[('read', '4, "2387 878 750 226 0 163 0\\n", 512', '25')]
[('read', '4, "", 487', '0')]
[('close', '4', '0')]
[('openat', 'AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9392/stat", O_RDONLY', '4')]
[('read(4, "9392 ', 'strace) S 9330 9330 9 3481"..., 2048', '319')]
[('read', '4, "", 1729', '0')]
[('close', '4', '0')]
[('openat', 'AT_FDCWD, "/proc/9407/task", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY', '4')]
```